# KLO for operations over braids

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, computational-topology

KLO is a program that permits you to the do twistings, band operations over knots or Kirby diagram. However, I couldn't find a function on KLO that permits me to do the same thing over braids.

Is there a KLO for braids? I really like the GUI that they have.

Comment: I don't know of any such program. But depending on what you want to do, you could just add an unknot (representing the braid axis) to a KLO braid diagram and then work with the existing functions.